# Show that $2\cos(mp-nq)$ is one of the values of $\left( \frac{x^m}{y^n}+\frac{y^n}{x^m} \right)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

**Q**:If $2\cos p=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and $2\cos q=y+\frac{1}{y}$ then show that $2\cos(mp-nq)$ is one of the values of $\left( \frac{x^m}{y^n}+\frac{y^n}{x^m} \right)$
**My Approach**:$2\cos p=x+\frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow x^2-2\cos px+1=0$ solving this equation i get $$x=\cos p\pm i\sin p$$ and **similarly**,$$y=\cos q\pm i\sin q$$Because somehow i guess $$x^m=\cos mp\pm i\sin mp,y^n=\cos nq\pm i\sin nq$$ maybe needed.But now i get stuck. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to write

$$x=e^{\pm ip},y=e^{\pm iq}.$$

Then see what

$$\frac{x^m}{y^n}+\frac{y^n}{x^m}$$

simplifies to.

Comment: Using your hint i get $\frac{(e^{\pm ipm})^2+(e^{\pm iqn})^2}{e^{\pm i(qn+pm)}}$.How to get figure out this?

Comment: This looks a lot like $e^{it}+e^{-it}$ for some value of $t$. What value?

Answer (score 0):

As we know form before$$x+{1\over x}\ge 2\quad,\quad x>0$$and $$x+{1\over x}\le -2\quad,\quad x<0$$therefore$$2\cos p\ge 2\text{ or }2\cos p\le -2$$which leads to$$x=\pm 1$$similarly$$y=\pm1$$case $1$: $x=y=1$
$$2\cos(mp-nq)=2\cos(m2k_1\pi-n2k_2\pi)=2$$which is valid.
case $2$: $x=y=-1$ $$2\cos(mp-nq)=2\cos(m(2k_1\pi+\pi)-n(2k_2\pi+\pi))=2\cos((m-n)\pi)=2\cdot(-1)^{m-n}=(-1)^{m-n}+(-1)^{n-m}={x^m\over y^n}+{y^n\over x^m}$$
the 2 other cases hold either then the statement is true.

Comment: $-1\leq \cos p\leq 1$ which implies $-2\leq 2\cos p\leq 2$ and you wrote $x=\pm 1$ how can you say that?Can you give me a logic to assume it.Thanks for your efforts :) @Mostafa Ayaz

Comment: You're welcome. This means that we have $-2\le x+{1\over x}\le2$which is possible only if $x=1$ or $x=-1$

Comment: Note: This answer assumes that $x,y$ are necessarily real, which I don't think is a reasonable assumption given the context of the problem.